# Need to format bing map custom info box

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have a bingmap in my windows phone 7 application. Bing map have lot of pushpins and infoboxes. Now the info box not good for looking.

The infobox XAML code as follow

```
 <my:MapLayer>
                        <Grid x:Name="Infobox" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,-115,-15,0">
                            <Border Width="300" Height="210" Background="Black" Opacity="0.7" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5"/>
                            <StackPanel Height="200" >
                                <Button Name="btnClose" Content="X" FontSize="17" Click="btnClose_click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" />
                                <Grid Height="180" Margin="5">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding PropertyImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60" Height="80"></Image>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="20" Width="220" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="5" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </my:MapLayer>
```

now the output is look like this[image: InfoboxOutput]

I need to adjust the height of the infobox and align the image.
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of alignment do you wish to have? perhaps attach a simple wire-frame? to make the image align to the top,

```
<Image Source="{Binding PropertyImage}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60" Height="80"></Image>
```

To set the height if the textbox to a fixed height, just change hte height from auto to whatever value you want, eg 100

To set the height of the grid (info box) again assign the height attribute to the grid

```
<Grid Height="100" x:Name="Infobox" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,-115,-15,0">
```